# Calculating the length of tape when it is wound up

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

**Goal**: *calculate the length of a cylindrical roll of tape given the thickness of the tape, the internal and external diameter of the roll.*

Firstly, I considered the roll of tape to be a bunch of concentric "circles" rather than a spiral.

Let

- $L=$  length of the tape
- $t=$ thickness of the tape
- $d-2t=$ internal diameter (diameter of the cardboard in the middle)
- $D=$ external diameter (diameter of the largest circle)
- $\alpha= \frac{D-(d-2t)}{2t}$ (the total number of circles of tape)

Then,

$$L=\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha-1} \pi(d+2it)$$

$$=\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha-1} \pi d + \sum_{i=1}^{\alpha-1} 2\pi it$$

$$=\alpha \pi d + \alpha (\alpha -1) \pi t$$

$$=\alpha \pi [d + (\alpha -1)t]$$

I have tested this formula for a few different values of $\alpha$, $d$ and $t$ and it seems to give the correct answer.

However, a roll of tape is not a bunch of concentric circles.

Is there any way to calculate the exact length of tape given these parameters?

Furthermore, how effective would using the formula above be?

Comment: [Seems similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633704/the-length-of-toilet-roll), no?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the area of rolled tape and that would be equal to the area of wounded up tape.
[image]

Comment: that is not what I am asking

Comment: @ConnorGaughan, But didn't you ask this: ...Is there any way to calculate the exact length of tape given these parameters?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have said "using these parameters" as the parameters don't make sense when we have a spiral instead of concentric circles, my bad (inner and outer diameters don't exist right?)

Comment: @ConnorGaughan, Since the thickness of an usual tape is very thin then this method is quite accurate, but when it comes to a noticeable thick material then we need a different way of calculation.

Comment: I have posted a similar question (about the thickness of a toilet paper) in my FB. I found your picture is much nicer than mine. Can I borrow it?

Comment: @Mick, Yes of course my friend, you can use it.