# What is the equation of adhesive tape?

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

[image]

I know that equation of spiral is $r*e^\theta$ but it seems that it can't depict fragment of adhesive tape irrespective of the value of $r$.
So, I was wondering what could be the equation of it.
Surely, it isn't a bunch of circles brought together to form a disc.

What would have been the case if its curvature was changing at every point?

Comment: @Arthur Undoubtedly the OP was thinking about the [logaritmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) $r=Ae^{k\theta}$ and just unwittingly overloaded symbols. Admittedly confusingly enough. Anyway, as Fabian's answer explains, we need an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) here. A similar spiral is seen as the groove on vinyl records.

Comment: May be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633704/the-length-of-toilet-roll could be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know the thickness $d$ of the tape. The equation is then determined from the fact that $$r(\theta+2\pi) = r(\theta) + d. \tag{1}$$

With the additional assumption that the increase of radius is constant, $$r'(\theta) = c, \tag{2}$$
which is fulfilled once you are far away from the initial part of the tape (where the function depends on a lot of details of the material of the tape).

Integrating (2) from $\theta$ to $\theta+2\pi$ and using (1), we obtain the relation
$$ 2\pi c =d $$
which determines the constant $c$.

So the equation of the tape is given by
$$ r(\theta) = \frac{d}{2\pi} \theta.$$