# Using differential equations to determine the number of rolls on a roll of toilet paper

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, puzzle

**Puzzle:** A role of toilet paper has $180$ sheets on it. The outside is covered with exactly two sheets. The inside around the cardboard cylinder is covered by exactly one. Question of the puzzle: how many layers of toilet paper are on the roll of toilet paper?

**The "Given" Solution:** One way to solve this is by saying that the average round is covered by $1.5$ sheets, so therefore the answer is $120$ (I have no source for whether this is actually correct)

**I Tried:** I tried to solve it with a differential equation, but ultimately failed:  Let $S$ be the number of toilet paper sheets on the roll, and $n$ the number of rotations.

I think the number of sheets per rotation depends linearly on the number of rotations at a given point, because with every rotation the toilet role becomes more thick, so:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}S}{\mathrm{d}n}=kn.$$

This equation is separable, so
$$dS=(kn)\,\mathrm{d}n.$$

Integrate to get
$$S=\frac{1}{2}kn^2+C.$$

Now we need to find the values of constants $k$ and $C$: we know that when $S=1$ then $n=1$ and also when $S=180$ then $\frac{dS}{dn}=2$.

But now I am stuck.

**My Question:** What would be the correct way of solving this problem *using differential equations*?

This question is also linked to this question: [Toilet paper puzzle (question 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651513/toilet-paper-puzzle-question-2)

Comment: I have thought about this problem for years and never could think of the right way to set it up...

Comment: You could see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633704/calculating-the-length-of-the-paper-on-a-toilet-paper-roll).

Comment: also this is related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3154201/532409

Answer (score 3):

Use the "sheets" as units of length, so the total length is $L=180$, the "inner" radius is $r_i = 1/(2\pi)$, the "external" one is $r_e = 2/(2\pi)$. Assume that the paper draws a spiral and makes $n$ loops (not necessarily an integer).
Then, we parametrize this spiral in terms of the angle $t \in [0, 2 n \pi]$ (I use rad for angles, so that $n$ is the number of layers). 
The radius is slowly increasing from $r_i$ to $r_e$, say linearly:
$$
r(t) = r_i +(r_e-r_i) \frac{t}{2 n \pi}
$$
We have 
$$
L = \int_0^{2 \pi n } dt  \sqrt{ r(t)^2 + r'(t)^2} \approx \int_0^{2 \pi n } dt \,     r(t) =   n \pi (r_e + r_i)
$$
This gives that the number of loops (or layers) is 
$$
n \approx \frac{L}{\pi (r_e + r_i)} = 2L/3 = 120
$$
Note: the approximation is valid if the spiral is "spiralling out" slowly. Otherwise the line of reasoning is the same, but you have to deal with more complex calculations (i.e. taking the full square root term in the integral).

PS: it is not explicitly with differential equations, but there is an integral. Solving the integral above is equivalent to "integrate" the ODE
$$
\frac{dL(n)}{dn}  \approx 2 \pi \, \frac{r_e + r_i}{2}
$$
You have to integrate this simple ODE with the initial condition $L(0) = 0$ till you touch the value $L(n) =180$.

Comment: This can not be correct, with 60 layers you get less than $2\times 60=120$ sheets. Did you lose a factor 2 somewhere?

Comment: Could be, let me check.. or maybe it is the approximation that is not good. But the line of reasoning seems correct.

Comment: Do it a-la the Gauß myth. Take an inner layer and the same layer from the outside, as they have about constant length, they have combined 3 sheets. Et voi-la, you end up with 60 inner and 60 outer layers, making a total of 120.

Comment: Yes, there is a missing 2, very easy to correct! I edit the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $\frac {dS}{dR}=kR$ is not correct because at $R=0$ you would have $\frac {dS}{dR}=0$.  Either you need to measure $R$ from the center and start the wrap at an $r \gt 0$ (which I would recommend) or you need to measure $R$ from the start of the wrap and then $\frac {dS}{dR}=k(R+r)$ where $r$ is the starting radius.

Let us use your solution $S=\frac 12kR^2+C$.  When $R=r$ we have $S=0$, so $S=\frac 12k(R^2-r^2)$.  Then we have $S=180$ when $R=2r$, so $180=\frac 12k\cdot 3r^2, 2=k\cdot 2r.$  This gives $k=\frac 1r, 180=\frac 32r, r=120$ and the outer radius is $2r=240$ so there are $120$ turns.

Comment: I meant R to be the amount of revolutions; not the Radius...

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  They are related by a factor $2\pi$.  We can measure $r$ in rotations as well.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand a bit on the last paragraph? The steps are not all obvious to me...

Comment: And, how would you do the calculation in rotations? After all, we want to know the number of rotations.

Comment: $R$ and $r$ are measured in rotations, not in length here.  We claim it takes $120$ turns to get from nothing to $r$ and another $120$ to get to $R$.  The radius is proportional to this, but we don't know the constant, which depends on the ratio of the thickness to the length of the sheets.

Comment: The point is that you have to set the zero of $R$.  If it is the first sheet of the problem, we need to be able to have a constant offset.  I set the zero of $R$ at zero radius and $r$ is the value where we start counting the $180$ sheets of the problem.  We find $r=120$ so if we started winding at zero radius we would have $120$ sheets to get to the point that a sheet is one circumference, which is where we start counting.  The first $r$ turns got us to where we start counting.  The next $R$ turns double the radius because of what we are given for the circumference.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand that one cannot solve this puzzle using continuous functions. We can make an **approximation** however. This is how that would work:

$S$=total amount of sheets

$n$=number of completed rounds

We know that the growth of the amount of Sheets (S) per Round (n) is constant. Why? Because it is depending om the circumference which grows linearly with the radius with $2\pi r$.

Therefore the **second** derivative of $S(n)$ is constant: $S''(n)=C_1$

The **first** derivative is therefore: $S'(n)=C_1n+C_2$

In round $0$ the amount of sheets per round is $1$, so we can approximate: $S'(0)=C_2\approx 1$

In the last round (when we used up all $180$ sheets of toilet paper) the amount of sheets per round is $2$, so we can approximate: $S'(n_{180})=C_1 n_{180}+1\approx 2$

And we can conclude that $C_1=\frac{1}{n_{180}}$

So:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{S'(n)=\frac{1}{n_{180}}n+1}$$

We can integrate to find: $S(n)=\int S'(n)dn=\frac{n^2}{2n_{180}}+n+C_3$

$S(0)=C_3=1$

So:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{S(n)=\frac{n^2}{2n_{180}}+n+1}$$

Now we can take $S(n_{180})=\frac{n_{180}^2}{2n_{180}}+n_{180}+1=180$

To find that after $180$ sheets, the approximate amount of completed rounds is $n_{180}=\frac{358}{3}=119\frac{1}{3}$

Now we can also take the inverse to find that:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{n(S)=\sqrt{\frac{716}{3}S+14001\frac{7}{9}}-\frac{358}{3}}$$

With a derivative of:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{n'(S)=\frac{358}{3\sqrt{\frac{716}{3}S+14001\frac{7}{9}}}}$$

Now I see why $S'(n)$ is lineair, but $n'(S)$ is not lineair! Which was what I was trying to get my head around when asking this question.

Answer (score -1):

The following is simple lateral area calculation:

Let outer,inner radii be  (R,r) respectively.
Since circumferences $2 \pi r , 2 \pi R $ proportional to $(r,R)$are given double,

$$ \dfrac{R}{r}=2 \tag1$$
It is given that total toilet paper length when unrolled 
$$ L= 180\, (2 \pi r)\tag2$$

Let effective toilet paper thickness be $t$. The lateral visible layered packed area of paper roll cylinder between radii $(R,r)$ is
$$ L\cdot t= \pi (R^2-r^2) \tag3$$
Eliminate L between (2) and (3) and simplify and  factor it
$$ 360 r= \dfrac {(R-r)(R+r)}{t} \tag4$$
Plug in from(1) and simplify to eliminate R
$$ 120 =\dfrac{r}{t} \tag5$$
Number of layers by tight roll winding the layers
$$n =  \dfrac{R-r}{t} =  \dfrac{r}{t}  \tag6 $$
and lastly from (5) and (6)
$$ n= 120 \tag7$$

And yes, it comes to the same result by integrating linear variation to second degree with smaller radius of roll boundary condition:
$$S=\frac{1}{2}kR^2-\frac{1}{2}kr^2,\,k= 2 \pi, $$
in other words effectively same as (3) with (2).

Comment: The question specifically asks how differential equations can be used to solve the problem.  If one allows other methods, then the question becomes a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633704/).  Your answer does not attempt to answer the question which was asked.

Comment: Mentioned at the end about using differential equations also.. Using differential equations, appeared to me like shall we say.. overkill? We like to  be nice with a soft indication of an easier option with an implied suggestion.

Comment: I agree that using differential equations is overkill.  However, if you want to write an answer that uses some other technique, then such a question already exits.  Answer *that* question.  *This* question is about using differential equations.