# How many rolls can fit in a 40HC Container?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, area, volume

We are trying to figure out a formula to find how many fabric rolls can we fit in a 40HC Container.

###### [40HC Container Dimensions](https://www.icontainers.com/help/40-foot-high-cube-container/#:%7E:text=Dimensions%20of%20the%2040%2Dfoot%20high%20cube%20container&text=The%2040%2Dfoot%20high%20cube%20container%27s%20dimensions%20are%3A,wide%20x%208%27%2010%E2%80%9D%20high):

- Measure: Millimeters
- Length:   12,032
- Width:    2,350
- Height: 2,700

###### Known variables:

- Width of the roll: 220cm
- Grams per meter2 of the fabric: 200grams per meter2
- Max.Weight of each roll: 30kg
- Total Lenght Requested: 10.000mt

If the grams per meter2 of the fabric is of 200gr and the total requested amount of fabric is of 10.000mt then we will have 2000kg of fabric. And if the maximum weight a roll can have is of 30kg then we end up with 66 rolls of equal weight and equal diameter and 1 roll slightly less heavy and in total that makes 67 rolls.

Which formulas would we need to employ in order to find how much space(%) these rolls will occupy in a 40HC container?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider how the rolls are arranged.  Since the 2200mm width is close to 2350mm I would align them along the width.  That wastes the last 150mm of the width.  Next you need the diameter of a roll.  We don't have how thick the fabric is and even if we did we wouldn't know how tightly the rolls are wound.  It would be best to measure one.  Finally there is the question of how the rolls pack.  They might be rigid cylinders, in which case the [densest packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Densest_packing) is about $90\%$ efficient.  They might squish down into squares under the weight and be more efficient.  They might vary somewhat in diameter and not pack as well as you hope.  I would probably start with $85\%$ as a guess and see how it goes.

Comment: Lenght and width of single roll is a known variable. Wouldn’t be enough to figure out the diameter when it is rolled? As they are fabrics and they’re somewhat rigid we understand that our calculations will never be 100% and we are okay with an empty space tolerance up to 10%.

Comment: No because you need the effective thickness of a turn of the fabric around the roll.  You could see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633704/calculating-the-length-of-the-paper-on-a-toilet-paper-roll)